# Databinding : InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-databinding

For security needs I'm using the *char array* version of `setText` to avoid using `String` version.

```
public final void setText (char[] text, 
                int start, 
                int len)
```

***BindingAdapter :***

```
public class DataBindingAdapter {
    @BindingAdapter("android:text")
    public static void setCharArray(ClearableEditText view, char[] value) {
        if(value == null) return;
        Log.v("BindingAdapter", String.valueOf(value));
        view.setText(value, 0, value.length);
    }

    @InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:text")
    public static char[] getArrayFromText(ClearableEditText view) {
        int length = view.getText().length();
        char[] password = new char[length];

        view.getText().getChars(0, length, password, 0);

        Log.v("BindingAdapter", String.valueOf(password));

        return password;
    }

}
```

***Emulator behavior :***

But the issue is when I enter **ABCD** in a `EditText` I got **DCBA** displayed plus the focus stay always in the beginning of the `EditText`.

***Real device behavior :***

Only the first char is displayed.

***Logs :***

> 2020-02-04 17:37:43.760 4110-4110/com.bla V/InputMethodManager:
>   Starting input: tba=com.bla
>   ic=com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection@3e6e221
>   mNaviBarColor -16750956 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible :
>   true , NavTrans : false 2020-02-04 17:37:43.760 4110-4110/com.bla
>   D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0 2020-02-04 17:37:43.767
>   4110-4110/com.bla  I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner -
>   mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO `CharArray` sucks with databinding because there is no issue when I change `CharArray` to `String` which mean the `equals` method is broken with the genrated code.

```
    @BindingAdapter("android:text")
    public static void setCharArray(EditText view, char[] value) {
        if(value == null) return;

        int length = view.length();
        char[] password = new char[length];
        view.getText().getChars(0, length, password, 0);

        if (Arrays.equals(value, password)) {
            Log.v("BindingAdapter out" + view.getId(), String.valueOf(value));
            view.setText(value, 0, value.length);
        }
    }
```

**Edit 1 : Better solution**

Use a [custom class](https://github.com/pac4j/pac4j/issues/809#issuecomment-275657007) that implement `CharSequence` and hence the adapter version of [setText](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/data-binding/+/refs/heads/studio-master-dev/extensions/baseAdapters/src/main/java/androidx/databinding/adapters/TextViewBindingAdapter.java#68) is `CharSequence` based there is no need to have a `BindingAdapter` in my side.

```
class SecureString(value: CharArray?) : CharSequence {
    @Transient
    private val value: CharArray

    init {
        requireNotNull(value) { "Value must not be null" }
        this.value = value
    }

    override val length: Int
        get() = value.size

    override fun get(index: Int): Char = value[index]

    override fun subSequence(start: Int, end: Int): CharSequence {
        throw UnsupportedOperationException()
    }

    fun clear() {
        Arrays.fill(value, '\u0000')
    }

    fun toCharArray(): CharArray {
        return value
    }

}
```

Adapt the `InverseBindingAdapter` to return `SecureString`:

```
    @InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:text")
    public static SecureString getSecureString(EditText view) {
        int length = view.length();
        SecureString password = new SecureString(new char[length]);

        view.getText().getChars(0, length, password.toCharArray(), 0);

        return password;
    }
```